# SQL Union on multiple Google Sheets / Workbooks

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I have two Google Sheets Workbooks.  They both have data in columns A through J.

I can import the ranges into a single workbook and name the data range, and a query works on one at a time:  `=QUERY(Phone, "Select A,B,C,G,H,I,J", 1)`

I've tried a couple different ways to Union the data, but nothing works quite like what I have in mind.

If it were SQL, I would do:

```
Select new.A, new.B, new.C, new.D
 from (
select A, B, C, D from Table1
Union
Select A, B, C, D from Table2
     )new
where new.A = 'incomplete'
```

edit1:
I was able to get this to work, but I'm not sure if there is a better way:

*phone and web are my named ranges
`=unique({QUERY({Phone}, "Select Col2, Col3, Col7", 1);query({Web}, "Select Col2, Col3, Col7",1)})`

Comment: What's your question? You have a working script.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to try something like this:

```
=QUERY({Phone; Web}, "Select Col2, Col3, Col7 where Col2 <>''",1)
```

or in case data in Col2 is numeric

```
=QUERY({Phone; Web}, "Select Col2, Col3, Col7 where Col2 is not null", 1)
```

Comment: I tried this first, but if you do this in Google Sheets, then it takes the Phone; Web and it appends the 2nd to the first.  So if at first I had 7 columns, now I have 7 more for a total of 14.  tldr; instead of stacking the queries like a SQL UNION would do, it puts them side by side.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet and show your expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

In the event someone else tries to do what I am, here's the full explanation of what I've done.

My goals:
 1. I am using jotForm to populate two Google Sheets.  They are different forms, but do capture some similar information.
 2. I want to keep the Response Sheets separate from the one used to Manage the information
 3. I want a summary of the Names and Phone numbers from the Response Sheets in one place, so the person responding can keep track of them, and add information pertinent to her.

I use `={importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{uniqueNumber}/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!A:J")}`
on each of the Google Sheets to bring both of them into my Management Sheet.
Then I make a Named Range out of each of them by going to the tabs, and using `Named Range Phone!A:J`

Then on the final tab (Report Tab) I put in the following:

`=unique({QUERY({Phone}, "Select Col2, Col3, Col7", 1);query({Web}, "Select Col2, Col3, Col7",1)})`

This works, though still not sure if it's the Best Answer.  It puts each of the queries into an array, and by placing the Unique in front of the arrays, allows both to be displayed.  If you don't have the unique, it will only show the 1st result set.